# Interrupt works too fast on the Arduino

Tags: arduino, interrupt

I know this sounds a bit funny :). But I am trying to eliminate possibilities:

On the [Arduino Uno](http://arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoBoardUno) I have attached an interrupt triggered on HIGH to a routine which only increments a volatile defined `long` counter. This counter is displayed on an LCD screen.
If I connect a pulse generator with a frequency of 1 Hz at TTL levels, I would expect the counter to increase with about 1 per second. However this is not the case.

As the frequency is 1 Hz (duty cycle 50%) could it be possible that once the counter is incremented the IRS is exited (and clears the interrupt flag) BUT: the `INT0` level is still HIGH so the ISR would be called again? At 1 Hz 50% duty, the HIGH would stay for 500 ms and at 16 mHz...

Comment: I'd expect the interrupt to trigger on a `transition` from low to high and not on a high level. There is nothing to trigger on a level. At what frequency is your ISR executed?

Answer (score 1):

*The processor at the heart of any Arduino has two different kinds of interrupts: “external”, and “pin change”. There are only two external interrupt pins on the ATmega168/328 (ie, in the Arduino Uno/Nano/Duemilanove), INT0 and INT1, and they are mapped to Arduino pins 2 and 3. These interrupts can be set to trigger on RISING or FALLING signal edges, or on low level. The triggers are interpreted by hardware, and the interrupt is very fast. The Arduino Mega has a few more external interrupt pins available.*

So as commented: It triggers on an edge!

See more details on the [Arduino Playground](http://playground.arduino.cc/Code/Interrupts) web page.

Answer (score 1):

Two electrical reasons can explain why interrupt does not function as you need.

1- The pulse generator output and MCU input can have an impedance mismatch, which can cause ringing on the waveform edges.  For example, if your function generator has a 50 ohm output capable of generating high frequencies you might see a problem driving a high impedance input like the Arduino at low frequency.

The name "pulse generator" makes me think this is a 50 ohm out device intended to make very short pulses with sharp edges. In such a case, you add a terminating resistor at the destination (load) to match the impedance of the source (pulse generator).  For a 50 ohm output, 47 ohm would be close enough.  If the output is 100 kohm, then place a matching resistor at the Arduino.

2- Just the opposite, the generator waveform edges may be so slow that the voltage passes through TTL 0 to 1 transition multiple times.  If you have noise on your signal input, a slow edge could be causing multiple triggers.  For example, if you are picking up some 60 Hz ripple from a power supply and grounding issues, your square wave edges won't be as square as you think.

In such cases hysteresis is a solution.  There are many ways to de-glitch (debounce) in code.  There is no answer that is right for all problems.  A simple example would be that the ISR you require that the input reads high twice in a row for the edge to be accepted.

Comment: Thank you all for the response. The problem is solved. #$%$#%^&$#@ Got the connections wrong..... INT0 = pin 2 and INT1 = Pin3.... Works like a charm nog.